# put component on side of search field

Tags: html, css

I am developing a web application and would like my EntreCadastre-se|Carrinho menu to be next to the text field, but it is getting underneath

[image]

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="imagens/eccomerce.JPG" alt="principal" id="imagem_principal">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="busca"><input type="text" id="campo_busca" placeholder="O que você procura?"><button type="submit" onclick="" class="buscar_produto "><i class="fa fa-search" action="" ></i></button> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    <ul class="menu_2">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          Entre/Cadastre-se <span class="caret"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="carrinho btn btn-default">Carrinho <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ( )</button>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong here is your math. Like @efkin said you have only 12 columns. But you have defined three divs with col-6. That means 3*6 = 18.
When you want 3 columns with equal size on one row you have to use col-4 for each, because 3*4 = 12.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row">

        <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="imagens/eccomerce.JPG" alt="principal" id="imagem_principal"  >
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-4">

            <div class="busca"><input type="text" id="campo_busca" placeholder="O que você procura?"><button type="submit" onclick="" class="buscar_produto "><i class="fa fa-search" action="" ></i></button> </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-4">

            <ul class="menu_2">

                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">

                                    Entre/Cadastre-se <span class="caret"></span>  


                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="carrinho btn btn-default">Carrinho <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ( )</button>
                </div>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: it is already in a column with col-6, the problem is when it decreases the width of the page the menu is below the search field and not the side that is the problem